# Timed out creating vms

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy node on google cloud platform specifically "make a hello world app" from [https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/].

After running "gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml --promote" command at Goole cloud sdk shell. It always ending "Timed out creating vms".

I don't know what's wrong, how can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use "--docker-build local" instead.